# MSBUILD errors on the Visual studio online

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, msbuild, tfsbuild

Team,

I have recently converted my project from .net framework version 4.0 to 4.6 using VS 2017. All is ok when i do a manualy build on my local computer.

But when i checkin and do a CI build, its gives the following error

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets (3075): Could not find file 'obj\Release\MyApplication.exe

I am not sure what it is...i have got 25 projects under a solution and there is nothing called as Myapplication.exe.

Can anyone please help me ?

Comment: Look in the project files for that particular string.

Comment: Hello Daniel...Which string are you  speaking of ?  obj\Release\MyApplication.exe...its not there anywhere? is it something to do with the release build? I already did that put all the projectsunder release and did a build on the local server and did a CI build.

Comment: The string *MyApplication.exe*. It's coming from *somewhere*. That *somewhere* is probably buried in your project files.

Comment: You can generate a binary log using the `-bl` argument to msbuild and looking at the log using the [MSBuild Binary and Structured Log Viewer](http://msbuildlog.com). You'd need to use the VS 2017 version of MSBuild though, not the outdated MSBuild version that ships as part of .NET Framework.

Comment: Found out...its the old lame name for the powershell project I have it as a project and is not building up due to "Unknow package type:console"  in the file PowershellProTools.targets

Comment: so... you could mark this as answered